# Вывести ссылку если есть запись в таблице

Tags: php, mysqli

Есть таблица tbl_uploads где хранятся пути к изображениям (рентгенам). Есть таблица priem где хранится записи приёма пациента. Надо сделать так если есть в таблице   tbl_uploads  снимок рентгена которая относится к данному приёму то вывести ссылку. А если нет то просто текст что нет рентгена. 
Делаю так сначала пихаю в массив поле sessid (поле где хранится номер приёма) из таблицы tbl_uploads

```
$rentresult =  mysqli_query($con, "SELECT sessid FROM tbl_uploads WHERE size = $id ;" );
$rent = array();
while( $rowr = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rentresult ) ) {
$rent[] = $rowr['sessid'] ;
```

Потом вторым запросом когда вытаскиваю все записи из таблицы priem проверяю есть ли номер сессии в массиве `$rent[]`  и если нет то текст нет рентгена а если есть то ссылка

```
$result2 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM priem WHERE card_id=$id")  or 
die("<p>Не удается выбрать запись из базы данных</p>". mysqli_error($con));
?><?php    while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2 )) { 
 $has_xray='Нет рентгена'; if (in_array($row2['sessid'] , $rent))  { $has_xray='Есть 
рентген'; }
```

И наконецто таким образом вывожу на экран

```
<td>    
<?php echo $has_xray ; ?>
</td>
```

Вся беда в том что даже когда в таблице есть рентген он всё равно показывает что нет рентгена. Где я допускаю ошибку ? может условие, может проверяю не так ?

Comment: А почему условие `size = $id` ? Судя по названию колонки в size должен лежать размер чего то (видимо файла) и какое отношение имеет размер в некому id как то не ясно ...

Comment: сделайте `var_dump($rent);` - все ли там нормально?

Comment: да это название столбца там раньше хранились размеры а сейчас id )

Comment: Сейчас сделаю var_dump

Comment: array(1) { [0]=> string(29) "pref_5958e99e612065.35093038 " } ' это значит что он показывает именно sessid